# Mac C++20 and 17 , std::uncaught_exceptions

Tags: c++, macos

When compiling my C++20 library on Mac I have this issue:

```
error: 'uncaught_exceptions' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12

    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Applications/anaconda3/envs/wood-dev/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Applications/anaconda3/envs/wood-dev/include -DVERSION_INFO=\"1.0.0\" -Isrc/frontend/src/3rd_party/Clipper2Lib/include/ -Isrc/frontend/ -Isrc/frontend/src/wood_pybind11/include_cpp/ -Isrc/frontend/src/wood/include/ -I/Applications/anaconda3/envs/wood-dev/include/eigen3 -I/Applications/anaconda3/envs/wood-dev/include -I/Applications/anaconda3/envs/wood-dev/include/python3.8 -c src/frontend/src/wood/include/cgal_box_util.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/src/frontend/src/wood/include/cgal_box_util.o -DVERSION_INFO=\"1.0.0\" -std=c++17 -fvisibility=hidden -DCGAL_DEBUG=1
   In file included from src/frontend/src/wood/include/cgal_box_util.cpp:1:
   In file included from src/frontend/src/wood/include/../../../stdafx.h:56:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h:21:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2/complement.h:27:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Gps_segment_traits_2.h:24:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2/Gps_polygon_validation.h:23:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2/Gps_on_surface_base_2.h:26:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Arrangement_on_surface_2.h:3098:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Arrangement_2/Arrangement_on_surface_2_global.h:36:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/No_intersection_surface_sweep_2.h:33:
   /usr/local/include/CGAL/Multiset.h:1574:3: error: 'uncaught_exceptions' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12
     CGAL_destructor_assertion_catch(
     ^
   /usr/local/include/CGAL/assertions.h:96:82: note: expanded from macro 'CGAL_destructor_assertion_catch'
   #  define CGAL_destructor_assertion_catch(CODE) try{ CODE } catch(...) { if(std::uncaught_exceptions() <= 0) throw; }
                                                                                    ^
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:132:63: note: 'uncaught_exceptions' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
   _LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTIONS int uncaught_exceptions() _NOEXCEPT;
                                                                 ^
   In file included from src/frontend/src/wood/include/cgal_box_util.cpp:1:
   In file included from src/frontend/src/wood/include/../../../stdafx.h:70:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh.h:18:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh/Surface_mesh.h:19:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh/IO.h:23:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/boost/graph/io.h:22:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/boost/graph/IO/WRL.h:15:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/IO/VRML.h:18:
   In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/IO/VRML/File_writer_VRML_2.h:22:
   /usr/local/include/CGAL/IO/VRML/VRML_2_ostream.h:35:5: error: 'uncaught_exceptions' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12
       CGAL_destructor_assertion_catch(
       ^
   /usr/local/include/CGAL/assertions.h:96:82: note: expanded from macro 'CGAL_destructor_assertion_catch'
   #  define CGAL_destructor_assertion_catch(CODE) try{ CODE } catch(...) { if(std::uncaught_exceptions() <= 0) throw; }
                                                                                    ^
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:132:63: note: 'uncaught_exceptions' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
   _LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTIONS int uncaught_exceptions() _NOEXCEPT;
                                                                 ^
```

This error is not directly related to CGAL, it is about a missing function in C++ 20 mac that does not have this method. Even if there is a way to ignore, or skip this error, I would be glad to know one.

Is there a way to define a macro to ignore this error?

I googled and searched on StackOverflow similar reports, but there is no solution found, just similar queries that do not work.

Comment: Did you pass `-std=c++??`?

Comment: Also note that `std::uncaught_exception` and `std::uncaught_exceptions` are different. The former was removed from the language.

Comment: First question yes. Senond question with "s". In this case is there any way to ignore this error?

Comment: *"if there is a way to ignore, or skip this error"* -- errors cannot be ignored. That is why they are errors, not warnings. You should stick to "skip" (or "avoid").

Comment: @JaMiT how to skip or avoid it?

Comment: Does anyone can help ?

Comment: @Petras *"Does anyone can help ?"* -- Please see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).  Other people are not operating on your schedule. The site considers two days (not just 8 hours) a reasonable time to wait for someone to answer. That being said, assuming both "Petras" accounts are the same person, you might want to consider ways to improve your question.